# Move Tensor to Cuda/Gpu on google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to move my tensor to cuda GPU on google colab but I am having an issue.

Originally it's a numpy

```
X_digits_train = torch.tensor(X_digits_train, dtype= torch.float32)

X_digits_train.device
   #returns device(type='cpu')


#Then I use
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
  #returns cuda

#Then I tried to move the tensor to cuda 
X_digits_train.cuda()

#However when I checked
X_digits_train.is_cuda
   #returns false
```

What Did I do wrong here?

Comment: you need to assign the result of tensor.cuda() to a variable

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.to('cuda')` to transfer your tensor to the GPU as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import torch


np_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
tensor = torch.from_numpy(np_array)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
tensor = tensor.to("cuda")
print(tensor.is_cuda)    #<---- should be True
```